# accordion code to angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a code of accordion that works for me when I'm not working with Angular in my page but when I work with Angular is not working I need to change it to angular code? If yes then how?

this is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".accordion-desc").fadeOut(0);
    $(".accordion").click(function () {
        $(".accordion-desc").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast')
        $(this).next().slideToggle(400);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to change code if you want to work with angular JS.

There are many libraries out there for accordion control you can use it in you application. like angular UI.

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

If you need step by step then you can refer below links

https://alexfeinberg.wordpress.com/2014/03/23/accordion-angular-js/

http://embed.plnkr.co/GvMsP2/